# Can't get AJAX post with PHP to work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have only recently started to learn AJAX and PHP and have been experimenting with MySql. I have been trying to create a webpage which passes variables into a php page, enters them into the database and then returns an echo indicating whether it was successful or not. For some reason i cant get the AJAX or Javascript (not sure) to work. It's probably something obvious so any help would be great! This is the AJAX and Javascript code which is invoked by an onClick -

```
< script langauge = "Javascript"  type ="text/javascript">
    function Generate(){

   var maxint = document.getElementById("Max").value;
   var minint = document.getElementById("Min").value;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "Untitled-1.php",
    data:  { 'senduser': maxint, 'sendpass': minint },
    success: function (msg) 
            { alert(msg) },
    error: function (err)
    { alert(err.responseText)}
});
} </script>
```

and this is the php code...

```
<?php
       $user = $_POST['senduser'];
       $password = $_POST['sendpass'];
     $con=mysqli_connect("host","username", "password","dbname");

      if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
 else{
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into Customers (password,username) 
                                VALUES ('$password','$user')");
         echo "You have signed up!";
        mysqli_close($con);
      }
           ?>
```

Comment: This `< script langauge` = **fail** - Plus, `Generate()` no call to function

Comment: Is your javascript running at all? cause i think you improperly wrote the script tag. remove the spaces between the `<` and `script` : `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: @Ibu I've fixed that and it still won't go to my php page.

Comment: @CameronGunn and this file `Untitled-1.php` is in fact the handler you're using, as well as your `Generate()` function? They are case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes, im stumped to why it aint working

Comment: Where do you call `Generate()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious thing is that you have a gap between the < and the script. It must be '

There are other smaller points but here is a working version. Note that the address of your page may need to be root relitive.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Generate()">Go Man Go</a>
<input type="text" value="12" id="Min" />
<input type="text" value="12" id="Max" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Generate() {

        var maxint = $("#Max").val();
        var minint = $("#Min").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: "Untitled-1.php",
            data: { senduser: maxint, sendpass: minint },
            success: function (msg)
            { alert(msg) },
            error: function (err)
            { alert(err.responseText) }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You're missing `name="senduser"` and `name="sendpass"` in inputs.

Comment: @Fred-ii- he is referencing the vals via jquery so you don't necessarily need the `name` set

Comment: Your wrong I'm afraid Fred, the name of the post parameters are referenced in the data array inside of the Ajax call. The values are referenced by the id tags and then sent via the ajax call, unlike a form post.

Comment: @matt.j.crawford ah ok. I mentioned that because of `$user = $_POST['senduser'];` etc, but I always always forget about Ajax taking the variable automatically. *I'll never learn* lol And way to go Matt, glad the OP found a solution.

Comment: @Ronnie My comment above this one will explain it, thanks Ronnie.

Comment: I go it working. All i did was copy that JQuery source you provided, i knew it was something obvious. Must of had a typo or something lol. Thanks guys anyways.